# Checking what type is passed into a generic method

Tags: dart

How do I check what is the type passed as type parameter for a generic method?

```
foo<T>() {
   // What type is T?
   // I want to able to do something like,
   // if T is String do something, if T is int do something else.
}
```

Answer (score 44):

You can use the equality (`==`) operator in the latest Dart SDK versions:

```
foo<T>() {
  if (T == String) {

  } else if (T == int) {

  }
}
```

One thing that's *not* trivial to do is inspect generic types, however:

```
foo<T>() {
  // Invalid syntax.
  if (T == List<String>) {}
}
```

In that case, you'll want more specialized methods:

```
fooOfT<T>(List<T> list) {
  if (T == String) {

  }
}
```

Comment: How about a type reflected at runtime? E.g. `Type t = (<int>[]).runtimeType` - say I get this type (`List<int>`) - how can I check if `type == List<int>`?

Comment: You can use `<int>[] is T` for Lists and `<int, int>{} is T` for Maps to check complex generic types.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on *why* you want to check the type.
If you want to special-case a few built-in types like `int` and `String`, you can use `T == int` or `T == String`.

For more complex types like `List<int>`, I'd recommend against using `==` because it only matches the exact type and might miss subtypes like `UnmodifiableList<int>` that you want to treat the same way (or risk breaking subtype substitutability). There is no direct way to compare two types for being subtypes, but you can use a helper function like:

```
/// Checks whether [T1] is a (not necessarily proper) subtype of [T2].
bool isSubtype<T1, T2>() => <T1>[] is List<T2>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy way:

```
bool check1<T>() {
  switch (T) {
    case Map<String, dynamic>: return true;
    case List<String>: return true;
    case String: return true;
    default: return false;
  }
}

bool check2<T>() {
  return [Map<String, dynamic>, List<String>, String].contains(T);
}
```

**<<Tested with Dart 2.17>>**