# Can i pass the generic type in dart programatically from a variable?

Tags: dart

Consider this code

```dart
final dynamic bar;

class Foo<T> {
  const Foo(this.bla) : assert(T == A, T == B);

  final T bla;
}
...
final Foo foo = Foo(bla); // Assert will trigerred because bla is dynamic even it is A type.
```

I don't know the bla type but i can assured its on a A type or B type.
I want to do something like this?

```dart
final Foo foo = Foo<bla.runtimeType>(bla);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write base class that encompasses class `A` and `B`. You should send class `Foo` that derives from this base class.

```
abstract class Base{
  void printName();
}
class A extends Base{
  A();
  @override
  printName(){
    print("A class");
  }
}
class B extends Base{
  B();
    @override
  printName(){
    print("b class");
  }
}
class Foo {
   Base bla;
   Foo(this.bla);
}



void main(){
  dynamic a=A();
  Foo fooA = Foo(a); 
  fooA.bla.printName();
  
  dynamic b=B();
  Foo fooB = Foo(b as Base); 
  fooB.bla.printName();
 }
```

You should be careful here `Foo fooB = Foo(b as Base);`. If this cast cannot be done, it will give an error.I suggest you use `try catch` block

[look here for generic type check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188729/checking-what-type-is-passed-into-a-generic-method)

because `T==A (any className)` in assert blog will not give correct result

[for more information](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43390)

Comment: In my case A and B is different class. Its from 3rd party, so i cannot change the structure, for example by giving it a superclass.